# 22.04 In the Nautilus File Manager, Right Clicking on a File, How Can I Restore The Pop-Out Menu "Open With..." Without An Additional Click or Dialog?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, nautilus, filemanager, nautilus-extensions

I recently updated from 18LTS to 22LTS, and one change that I dislike very much is that when right-clicking a file in the file manager, the "Open With" option, which used to have a pop-out menu that allowed you to directly select the application to use in one click, has been replaced by a single option "Open With Other Application", which then pops up an additional box and requires an additional click.

Although it is a small thing, I use this feature so frequently that it is quite cumbersome to have the additional click, especially given that the fact that the box appears in a new dialogue makes me do more work to navigate the mouse to the correct item in the list, whereas the menu would appear in a more predictable location. I.e. the new dialog location is fixed relative to the parent window, whereas the menu's location was relative to the menu itself, so the horizontal location of the list relative to the mouse cursor is highly variable, especially given that I am usually viewing large windows in list view when I am using this feature, and I may click anywhere horizontally on the list.

I would like to restore the old behavior, where there is a pop-out menu, and ideally I would like to do this without installing any additional software. I saw that there is [a Nautilus extension that does this](https://github.com/maoschanz/nautilus-open-with-menu). My preferred solution would be to do it without an extension, such as by enabling something in a configuration file or by getting an updated version that fixes the behavior. However, if this is not possible I would like to know how to install and set up this extension or perhaps some other one, to get this behavior back as a workaround or hack solution. The extension linked to is not well documented so I am a bit unclear what to do with it.

Also, if this has been a decision made by the developers, I would like to get in touch with them to encourage them to restore the original behavior. The new behavior is so inferior to the old that I find it very hard to imagine that this change was made intentionally, and I wonder if it was simply a glitch or oversight that could be easily corrected if it were simply brought to the right person's attention.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS used a GNOME version that was ~4 years later than the GNOME version used in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  The version used in 22.04 LTS is already somewhat old, with GNOME *developers* only recently releasing GNOME 45 which is used in Ubuntu 23.10; so your starting point as for what GNOME is now isn't what you're seeing anyway  (you're dislike appears to be GNOME decisions, not Ubuntu's).. *FYI: The April & October release cadence of Ubuntu is there to ~match GNOME's releases as much as possible*  This is a **Ubuntu Q&A support** site, not a *developer* comment site.

Comment: That makes sense. I'd still like to get this feature working without an inordinate amount of work on my part.

Comment: makes sense hopefully; I meant "*~4 years earlier*" when I said "*~4 years later*"... I also stuffed up "*Your*" instead saying 'You are' via "*You're*" etc... Sorry for typos/grammar etc.   regardless I believe you're seeking what is an "*inordinate amount of work*" and potentially will cause your system to become a *frakensystem*...  The easy fix is to use another tool instead of `nautilus`, ie. any of the many forks is where I'd look (MATE's `caja`, Cinnamon's `nemo`, Xfce's `thunar` etc... whichever works the way you want it to work, and leave `nautilus` which is highly DE specific alone

Comment: Xfce's `thunar` is **not** a fork, regardless you'll know what I mean.... there are many others to choose from too, but I was trying to *list* in order of being most efficient on a GNOME environment